# Right click editing menu disabled ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing, polygon-creation

Editing Polygon feature in FGDB, Create Features, Click Rectangle (in Construction tools), right click, unable to select any options (Absolute X, Y / Direction / Length) from popup menu.

Help? Haven't seen this one before.

Comment: I've had strange things happen in an edit session, but restarting ArcMap usually fixed it. Does this always happen? Is this a 10.0 version FGDB?